# Python spacing out 2048 board

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have code for a 2048 board:

```
count = 0
for i in range(16):
    print(nlist[i], end = ' ')
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        print("")
        count = 0
```

and this works fine if all the values are single digit numbers:

```
0 0 0 8
0 4 0 0 
0 0 2 2
0 0 0 0
```

but if I have multiple numbers with more than 1 digit:

```
16 0 2 2048
8 2 32 64
2 2 0 0
2048 2048 4096 4096
```

All the spacing gets messed up. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Calculate the length of the longest value, then pad every other value with spaces to be that length

Comment: I don't know how to put that solution into my code.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid writing custom functions for doing this. There are lots of python packages out there that can print stuff in a neat table.

My suggestion would be to use [PrettyTable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable)

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
t = PrettyTable(header=False, border=False)
for i in range(0,16,4):
    t.add_row(range(i, i+4))

print t
# 0   1   2   3  
# 4   5   6   7  
# 8   9   10  11 
# 12  13  14  15
```

Answer (score 0):

As Keatinge mentions in the comment, iterate over the array before printing and find the longest number.

```
length = max(map(lambda x: len(str(x)), nlist)) + 1
```

We take `nlist`, figure out the length of each number when written as text, then take the maximum and add one (the +1 is so that there's a space between the numbers). Then, inside the loop, we stringify the number we're looking at and add spaces as needed.

```
text = str(x)
text += ' ' * (length - len(text))
```

Complete example:

```
count = 0
length = max(map(lambda x: len(str(x)), nlist)) + 1
for i in range(16):
    text = str(nlist[i])
    text += ' ' * (length - len(text))
    print(text, end = '')
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        print()
        count = 0
```

Comment: Why not use `format`? That way short numbers could get centered.

Comment: How can you use format?